# Setting TLS1.2 on Apache Knox instance

Tags: tls1.2, apache-knox

I am looking for some ideas on disabling TLS 1 and 1.1 in order to get the TLS version 2 working on my Apache Knox appliance. I tried :

1. Add a line in the gateway-site.xml file

```xml
<property>
    <name>ssl.exclude.protocols</name>
    <value>TLSV1.1</value>
    <description>Excluded SSL protocols.</description>
</property>
```

2. Add the last line in the knoxsso.xml file :

```xml
  <topology>
    <gateway>
      <provider>
        <role>webappsec</role>
        <name>WebAppSec</name>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <param><name>xframe.options.enabled</name><value>true</value></param>
    <param><name>strict.transport.enabled</name><value>true</value></param>
      </provider>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try adding SSLv3, RC4, MD5withRSA, DH keySize < 768, TLSv1, TLSv1.1 to following property in /$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/java.security

```
jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3, RC4, MD5withRSA, DH keySize < 768, TLSv1, TLSv1.1
```

Restart knox and run following to verify:-

```
nmap -sV --script +ssl-enum-ciphers -p $(port) $(hostname -f)
```